# ASP.NET MVC5 KnockoutJS mapping "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJS' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Looking for some help with KnockoutJS and an MVC application I am working on.

I am attempting to use Knockoutjs to map a server side View Model to a Client side View Model then via the view add each client view model to a collection and (not in the below code) return back to the controller using AJAX.

Up to now when I attempt to add a View Model to the knockout array I receive the following error :

```
TrainingCourse.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJS' of undefined
```

My knockout script is as follows :

```
TrainingCourseViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    jsonData = data;
        self.rows = ko.observableArray([
        new TrainingCourseItemViewModel({
            "TrainLevel": 1, "TrainCourseTitle": null, "TrainProviderName": null, "TrainDateStarted": null,
                "TrainDateCompleted": null, "TrainHoursAttended": 0, "TrainCost": 0, "QualificationGained": false,
                "VoluntDateStarted": null, "VoluntDateEnded": null, "VoluntWhoWith": null, "VoluntHoursAttended": 0, "VoluntContactDetails": null,
                "WorkExpDateStarted": null, "WorkExpDateEnded": null, "WorkExpWhoWith": null, "WorkExpHoursAttended": 0, "WorkExpContactDetailsEmployer": null,
            "DateofPurchase": null, "Cost": 0, "PurchaseDetails": null, "PersonId": 0
        })
    ]);

    self.addRow = function () {
        self.rows.push(new TrainingCourseItemViewModel({
            "TrainLevel": 0, "TrainCourseTitle": null, "TrainProviderName": null, "TrainDateStarted": null,
            "TrainDateCompleted": null, "TrainHoursAttended": 0, "TrainCost": 0, "QualificationGained": false,
            "VoluntDateStarted": null, "VoluntDateEnded": null, "VoluntWhoWith": null, "VoluntHoursAttended": 0, "VoluntContactDetails": null,
            "WorkExpDateStarted": null, "WorkExpDateEnded": null, "WorkExpWhoWith": null, "WorkExpHoursAttended": 0, "WorkExpContactDetailsEmployer": null,
            "DateofPurchase": null, "Cost": 0, "PurchaseDetails": null, "PersonId": 0}));
    }

    self.removeRow = function (row) {
        self.rows.remove(row);
        calculateTrainingCost();
        calculateOverallTotal();
        trainingDateAutoCompleted();
    }

    function TrainingCourseItemViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
        }

}
```

The error is occurring at line 47 of that file which is the following :

```
function TrainingCourseItemViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
        }
```

The associated view is as follows :

```
@* Serialize model in to JSON *@
@{ string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);}



<h3>Add Training/Qualification</h3>
<div id="TrainingCourseViewModel">
    <table class="table table-hover">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CQFW Level</th>
                <th>Course Title</th>
                <th>Provider Name</th>
                <th>Date Started</th>
                <th>Date Completed</th>
                <th>Hours Attended</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Qualification Gained?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

            <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows" id="trainingPadding">
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1">@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.TrainLevel, new { @class = "form-control site-level-ddl trainingLevel", data_bind = "value: TrainLevel" })</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainCourseTitle" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainProviderName" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainDateStarted" class="form-control date-input datepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainDateCompleted" class="form-control date-input datepicker trainingDateCompleted hasDatepicker" onchange="trainingDateAutoCompleted()" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainHoursAttended" class="form-control" onkeyup="calculateTrainingCost()" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainCost" class="form-control trainingCost" placeholder="£0.00" onkeyup="calculateTrainingCost(), calculateOverallTotal()" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: QualificationGained" class="" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-1" style="width: 4%; text-align: center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeRow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>



    </table>

    <input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: addRow" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>

<!---Scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/KnockoutViewModels/TrainingCourse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var trainingCourseViewModel = new TrainingCourseViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
    ko.applyBindings(trainingCourseViewModel);
</script>
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated as I am pretty new to KnockoutJS...

Cheers

Comment: Add a `data` parameter in `TrainingCourseItemViewModel`: `function TrainingCourseItemViewModel(data)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In `TrainingCourseItemViewModel` you call `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);`, but `data` is undefined.  When you call  `new TrainingCourseItemViewModel({ ... })`, `TrainingCourseItemViewModel` don't get this object because it has not any parameter.

Comment: Thanks, tried adding as a parameter however i am still receiving the same error

Comment: Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/de3mn89j/3/.  I get your error when I don't load the mapping js.  Perhaps it is not loading correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle il do some testing based on that...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dom us fully loaded when you are creating view model instance and initiating the bindings.

If pure java script,
use,

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var trainingCourseViewModel = new TrainingCourseViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
    ko.applyBindings(trainingCourseViewModel);
 });
```

OR if you are using the jQuery framework,

```
$(function(){
   var trainingCourseViewModel = new TrainingCourseViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
    ko.applyBindings(trainingCourseViewModel);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work...i receive the same error now on page load

Comment: Add data parameter to the ,  function TrainingCourseItemViewModel(jsData) {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(jsData, {}, self);
        }

Comment: Press F12 on browser and check whether the knockout js and mapping plugin are downloaded to the browser. If the plugging is not in Script folder add it via package manager console. And get the child view model constructor function, function TrainingCourseItemViewModel(jsData) { var self = this; ko.mapping.fromJS(jsData, {}, self); } to the out side of the parent view model constructor function.

Comment: plugin is present within the script folder and same error when child vm is external to the parent....

Comment: It seems that the mapping plugin is not loaded correctly. press F12 and see whether the mapping plugin is loaded.